# C# Pointer issues

Tags: c#, pointers

I have tried to use a pointer with a struct in C#, but some strange calculation occurs when I add an offset to the pointer:

```
     p_FILE_HEADER = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*)(p_DOS_HEADER +  p_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew);
```

```
  0000018a  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
  0000018d  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+14h]   
  00000190  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
  00000193  mov         edx,dword ptr [edx+14h] 
  00000196  mov         edx,dword ptr [edx+3Ch] 
  00000199  xor         ecx,ecx 
  0000019b  shl         edx,6   //strange
  0000019e  add         eax,edx 
  000001a0  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
  000001a3  mov         dword ptr [edx+0Ch],eax
```

Everything seems okay except the shift instruction, I don't get it why it would be here.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Here is the struct definition (yes it's part of the PE header)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1) ]
public unsafe struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
{      // DOS .EXE header


    public ushort e_magic;               //0x0      // Magic number     
    public ushort e_cblp;                //0x2      // Bytes on last page of file
    public ushort e_cp;                  //0x4      // Pages in file    
    public ushort e_crlc;                //0x6      // Relocations
    public ushort e_cparhdr;             //0x8     // Size of header in paragraphs
    public ushort e_minalloc;            //0xA      // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    public ushort e_maxalloc;            //0xC      // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    public ushort e_ss;                  //;0xE      // Initial (relative) SS value
    public ushort e_sp;                  //0x10      // Initial SP value
    public ushort e_csum;                //0x12      // Checksum
    public ushort e_ip;                  //0x14      // Initial IP value
    public ushort e_cs;                  //0x16      // Initial (relative) CS value
    public ushort e_lfarlc;              //0x18      // File address of relocation table
    public ushort e_ovno;                //0x1A      // Overlay number

  // [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public fixed ushort e_res[4];              //0x1C      // Reserved words
    public ushort e_oemid;               //0x24      // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    public ushort e_oeminfo;             //0x26      // OEM information; e_oemid specific
  //  [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public fixed ushort e_res2 [10];            //0x28      // Reserved words

    public uint e_lfanew;              //0x3C      // File address of new exe header

}
```

Comment: Obviously, the size of your structure is 64 bytes, thus the number added to a pointer to that structure is multiplied by 64, which is equivalent to left-shifting it by 6 bits. To add to the address proper, cast `p_DOS_HEADER` to `byte*`.

Comment: @Andrey it's not *that* obvious ;-) you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets walk through this for just a second.

> ```
> p_FILE_HEADER = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*)(p_DOS_HEADER +  p_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew);
> ```

So you have some variable `p_DOS_HEADER` that is presumably an instance of `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`. You load your PE image into memory and lay this structure on top of it. So `p_DOS_HEADER.e_lfanew` tells you, how far from the start of the file, in bytes, is the 'new exe header'. `p_DOS_HEADER` tells you where in memory your 'file' starts.

In C#, pointer arithmetic works based off the size of the pointed-to type. `int* thing = ...; thing++` will cause thing to jump ahead four bytes (the size of `int`), not one byte. This is the same convention that most other pointer-capable languages support, like C++ or C.

However, the field you're reading - `e_lfanew` stores the offset in bytes. Thus, you want byte arithmetic.

You want something like this:

```
p_FILE_HEADER = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*)( (byte*)p_DOS_HEADER + p_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew);
```

Comment: Thank your so much .                                                                                   I get it from your answer , because the struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER is 0x40  size in byte , so it shift left 6 bit as multiply 0x40 with the e_lfanew..